# ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have created a function with the code below to retrieve the count of blank spaces for each column in a table...however i encounter the error on executing for multiple rows Cant figure where the error conversion is the issue

```
set SERVEROUTPUT on
select  table_name,column_name,
get_rows( table_name,column_name) cnt
from all_tab_columns where table_name='TEST' 
/
```

the error:

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at "JAMES.GET_ROWS", line 31
ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-06512: at "JAMES.GET_ROWS", line 24
ORA-06512: at "JAMES.GET_ROWS", line 24
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
           occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
           assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
           attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
           declared NUMBER(2).
*Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
           that values do not violate constraints.




create or replace function get_rows( l_table in varchar2,l_column_name in varchar2 ) return number
        as
          l_session_name varchar2 ( 30 )   := 'UNDEFINED';
          l_owner        varchar2 ( 30 )   := 'JAMES';
          --l_table        varchar2(30)      := 'TEST';
          l_cnt          NUMBER        default NULL;
          sql_stmt       varchar2 ( 1000 ) := null;
          l_space        varchar2 ( 30 )   := ' ';
        begin
          select sys_context ( 'userenv','session_user' )
          into l_session_name
          from dual;
            for i in
          (select owner, table_name,column_name
          from all_tab_columns
          where table_name = l_table
          and owner         = l_owner
          and column_name = l_column_name
          order by column_id 
          )
          loop
            sql_stmt := 'SELECT COUNT('||i.column_name||') FROM ' || i.owner ||'.' || i.table_name || ' WHERE ' ||i.column_name|| '='||''' ''' ;

             execute immediate sql_stmt into l_cnt;

            end loop;
           return l_cnt ;
           EXCEPTION
          WHEN OTHERS THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('Returning Error : '||SQLERRM);
            RETURN SQLERRM;

        end;

    /
```

Answer (score 1):

The error messages references the `line 31` where the code has `RETURN SQLERRM;` which is trying to return a `alpha-numeric string` while the function must return a `number`, you can already see the error message by
`dbms_output.put_line('Returning Error : '||SQLERRM);`, so convert `RETURN SQLERRM;` to `RETURN NULL;`, and indeed reveal your main problem, that's `ORA-01722: invalid number` which raises.

This raises whenever your columns' data types are not `VARCHAR2`, `NVARCHAR` .. etc, but `DATE`, `NUMBER` .. etc.

Therefore, you can convert your cursor to

```
for i in
(
select owner, table_name, column_name, data_type
  from all_tab_columns
 where table_name = l_table
   and owner = l_owner
   and column_name = l_column_name
 order by column_id
 )
```

and add an if statement inside the loop as

```
if i.data_type in ('CHAR','VARCHAR2','VARCHAR','NCHAR','NVARCHAR2') then
  sql_stmt := 'SELECT COUNT('||i.column_name||') FROM ' || i.owner ||'.' || i.table_name || 
              ' WHERE ' ||i.column_name|| '='||''' ''' ;
else
  sql_stmt := 'SELECT COUNT('||i.column_name||') FROM ' || i.owner ||'.' || i.table_name || 
              ' WHERE ' ||i.column_name|| ' IS NULL';
end if;
```

Whenever you see raising no exception because of if statement, you can completely remove the exception part. Since you eventual aim should be getting rid of such exceptions.

Comment: It would be better to not catch the exception at all and just let the caller see it.

Comment: @AlexPoole right, actually, I think the same as a result aim. Kept the `dbms_output...` part inside exception block, just to watch what happens step by step get rid of exceptions eventually.

Answer (score 0):

the return type is the problem

```
 return to_number(SUBSTR(sqlerrm, 5, 9));
```

Comment: The second argument to `substr` is wrong; but why do this at all when you can just return `sqlcode`? (Or since the caller won't know that this was from an error and isn't a real valid response, return `null`; or even better, don't catch the exception at all....)

Comment: @AlexPoole exception should be handled if the written code goes into some exception!!!

Answer (score 0):

just use this:

```
begin
  ....
exception
  when others then
    DBMS_Output.Put_Line('Returning Error : ' || sqlerrm);
    return sqlcode;
end;
```

instead of this:

```
begin
  ....
   EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Returning Error : '||SQLERRM);
    RETURN sqlcode;

end;
```

The problem is your return type in the exception section. `sqlerrm` is not a number so you can not return it when you declared the return type of your function as number. Use `sqlcode` instead.